# Netezza DISK_FPGA_ERROR

Tags: netezza

I'm using Netezza with following information:

Model: N3001-010

NPS Software version: 7.2.0.6-P1

[image: Data Slices Screenshot]

When I try to query with simple statements such as:

```
select count(*) from table_name;
```

or

```
select * from table_name where date_col>='2015-12-01' and date_col<='2015-12-30' limit 1000;
```

the raised error is:

> ERROR [HY000] ERROR:  DISK_FPGA_ERROR : Status=0,0x4000
>   [COMPBADFIELDTYPE1] SPU=1010 Dev=31 Eng=11 LBA=32224515

This error does not occur systematically.

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error can indicate a disk page corruption, or some other fundamental issue, and your administrator should **immediately** open a support ticket to investigate and resolve this.  T